# Expected ';' but got ',' but below that same error doesn't appear in a .sol file

Tags: blockchain, contract

Hi so my problem is that in the trasnferFrom function where the address from is it tells me Expected ';' but got ','
but in the below function  safeTrasferFrom() is doesn't give me that error

```
   function trasferFrom() {
        address from,(Here Expected ';' but got ',')
        address to,
        uint256 tokennId
    } public override {
        require(
            _isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(),tokenId),
            "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved"
        );
        buildings[tokenId - 1].owner = to;
        _tranfer(from, to, tokenId)
    }
    function safeTrasferFrom() {
        address from,(but here works)
        address to,
        uint256 tokennId,
        bytes memory _data
    } public override{
        require(
            _isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(),tokenId),
            "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved"
        );
        buildings[tokenId - 1].owner = to;
        _safeTrasferFrom(from, to, tokenId, _data)
    }
```

I'm new to the blockchain and coding so it would be really nice to get some help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I fixed it lol my problem was that instead of

```
   function trasferFrom() {
        address from,(Here Expected ';' but got ',')
        address to,
        uint256 tokennId
    } public override {
        require(
            _isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(),tokenId),
            "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved"
        );
        buildings[tokenId - 1].owner = to;
        _tranfer(from, to, tokenId)
    }
```

it should have been

```
   function trasferFrom(
        address from,(Here Expected ';' but got ',')
        address to,
        uint256 tokennId
    ) public override {
        require(
            _isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(),tokenId),
            "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved"
        );
        buildings[tokenId - 1].owner = to;
        _tranfer(from, to, tokenId)
    }
```

now I've got another problem but it doesn't have nothing to do with this!